# How to sum all the number per table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on multiple table where you can add those input number

I have a drop box where i can choose how many table will i display from 1 to 10

```
Choose How many table 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

if i choose 2 there's a 2 table that will appeear

[Image for Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLva8.jpg)

Please see picture above

As you can see in the picture there's a sub quantity but in the 2nd table there's no because it didn't sum the numbers in the 2nd table.

Here's my html code for **Quantity**

```
<td style="text-align:center;">

<input type="text" name="<?php echo $ID?>" id="_aaa" pattern="^[0-9]+$" style="background:transparent; text-align:center; width:50px;" required> 

</td>
```

Html for **Sub Quantity**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table3" align='right'  style="margin-top:15px; width:30%;" >

            <tr>
                <th style='border: 1px solid;'>Sub Quantity </th>
                <td style='border: 1px solid; width: 150px; text-align:center;'><span id="_aaa_Sub"> </span></td>
            </tr>


</table>
```

Html for **Total Quantity**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table3" align='right'  style="margin-top:15px; width:30%;" >

            <tr>
                <th style='border: 1px solid;'>Total Quantity </th>
                <td style='border: 1px solid; width: 150px; text-align:center;'><span id="_aaa_Final"> </span></td>
            </tr>


</table>
```

and here's my **Javascript**

```
<script language="javascript">

    $(function () {
        //var inputs = $("input");
        var inputs = $("[id=_aaa]");


        inputs.blur(function () {
            var total = 0;
            $.each(inputs, function (input) {
                var num = parseInt(inputs[input].value);
                total += (!isNaN(num)) ? num : 0;
            });

            document.getElementById("_aaa_Sub").innerHTML =    total;

        })
    })


</script>       


<script language="javascript">

    $(function () {

        var inputs = $("[id=_aaa]");


        inputs.blur(function () {
            var total = 0;
            $.each(inputs, function (input) {
                var num = parseInt(inputs[input].value);
                total += (!isNaN(num)) ? num : 0;
            });

            document.getElementById("_aaa_Final").innerHTML =    total;

        })
    })

</script>
```

Can you please help me with my issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: At first - it's a bad practice to use "id" attribute for a few elements on the page. Try to use classes.

Comment: if there are dynamic multiple  tables then there is high chances that your  `ID`s are duplicate. So use `class` instead

Answer (score 0):

That's because your first JS function will be only called for one table as it's not in `each` loop.. So try to add the whole function inside `each`

And don't use `ID` as they should be unique try using `class` for sub

```
$(function () {

    var table = $('table');//or any identifier for your table
    $.each(table,function(i) {
    var inputs = $("[id=_aaa]");
    var self = this;

    inputs.blur(function () {
        var total = 0;
        $.each(inputs, function (input) {
            var num = parseInt(inputs[input].value);
            total += (!isNaN(num)) ? num : 0;
        });
        $(self).closest("#_aaa_Sub").innerHTML =    total;
    })
})
})
```